# Add Class to Object on Page Load or on Click

Tags: javascript, onclick, onload

This is my Current Code in my wordpress:

```
<div class="entry-content">
                <a href="<?php

                echo $currenturl.'?material=&type='.$get_type;
                ?>">All Materials</a>

                <?php
                $materials = get_field('materials',$valueid);
                foreach($materials as $id):?>
                    <a href="<?php
                        $matterm = get_term($id,'materials');
                        $matslug = $matterm->slug;
                        $mattitle = $matterm->name;
                        echo $currenturl."?material=".$matslug.'&type='.$get_type;
                        ?>"><?php
                            echo $mattitle;
                        ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
```

This is the Current Output:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <a href="#>Material 1</a>
    <a href="#>Material 1</a>

</div>
```

And I want the output of the code will be:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <a class="current" href="#>Material 1</a>
    <a href="#>Material 1</a>

</div>
```

and I have this Script on my header but it will not function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('entry').className = 'current';
};


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up class and id (or just left off the id). If you do `console.log(getElementById("entry"))`, I bet you get back `null`.

Comment: is this right sir?. <script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
  console.log(getElementById("entry"))
};

 
</script>

Comment: If you want to use ID in your javascript, you have to have it in the HTML.
<div class="entry-content" id="entry">

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to replace this.

```
window.onload = function() {
   var parentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('entry-content');
   parentDiv.childNodes[0].className = 'current';
};
```

Comment: where `OP` have defined `entry-content` id?

Comment: good, `document.getElementsByClassName('entry-content');` is always provides all selectors, so you should need to target only single selector try this `document.getElementsByClassName('entry-content')[0];`

Comment: yes later i take chilNodes[0] to get first Element... is it right??

Comment: this is not right.. `parentDiv` is array of all objects so you should use same as `childNodes[0]`

Comment: Use: `parentDiv[0].childNodes[0].className = 'current';`

Comment: this is the current code sir..still not function <div class="entry-content">
    <a href="<?php
    echo $currenturl."?type="."&material=".$get_material;
    ?>">All Types</a>

    <?php
    $materials = get_field('types',$valueid);
    $currenturl = get_permalink($valueid);
    foreach($materials as $id):?>
     <a href="<?php
      $matterm = get_term($id,'types');
      $matslug = $matterm->slug;
      $mattitle = $matterm->name;
      echo $currenturl."?type=".$matslug."&material=".$get_material; 
      ?>"><?php
       echo $mattitle;
      ?>
     </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
 document.getElementById('entry').className = 'current';
```

[`getElementById(ID)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) it's a javascript method and used for getting the element with the specific `ID`

And your HTML is not correct, you forgot the end `"` of href.

You should write your HTML like -

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <a id="entry" href="#">Material 1</a>
    <a href="#">Material 1</a>
</div>
```

After make above changes, your code works perfectly. [`See Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/u2QCp/1/)

Comment: Yes, IF you want to use getElementById() in your code. :)

Comment: but the code is looping the content for <a> <div class="entry-content">
   <a href="<?php
      echo $currenturl.'?material=&type='.$get_type;
                ?>">All Materials</a>

                <?php
       $materials = get_field('materials',$valueid);
       foreach($materials as $id):?>
       <a href="<?php
       $matterm = get_term($id,'materials');
       $matslug = $matterm->slug;
       $mattitle = $matterm->name;
       echo $currenturl."?material=".$matslug.'&type='.$get_type;
       ?>"><?php
       echo $mattitle;?>
       </a>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>